# print an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Hello I need help accessing elements of objects in my JavaScript
What's the error of this one

```
var people = [
    {
        name: "Jake",
        age: 20
    },
{
        name: "John",
        age: 23
    },
{
        name: "Mike",
        age: 21
    },
]



for (var i=0; i < 3 ;i++)
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML += "Name: " + people[i].name + "Age: "+ people[i].age +"\n";
```

I only need to write to the div the values of the array of objects

Comment: No error, what's the issue?

Comment: Maybe there is no "myDiv" on the page? Whatsoever we can't reproduce the error with the code given, please create a [mcve]

Comment: What error/unexpected behaviour are you actually experiencing? It looks ok to me, assuming the HTML matches the code. You haven't provided us all of the necessary information

Comment: Please mention the error that you are facing actually???

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 2):

There was nothing wrong with your Javascript. Check if you have written everything correct for `myDiv`. Here is my example and it worked fine.

Remember to put a `<br>` tag instead of `\n` and `" Age: "` instead of `"Age: "`. Good luck!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv">
        <div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>

    var people = [
        {
            name: "Jake",
            age: 20
        },
    {
            name: "John",
            age: 23
        },
    {
            name: "Mike",
            age: 21
        },
    ]

    for (var i=0; i < 3 ;i++)
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML += "Name: " + people[i].name + " Age: "+ people[i].age + "<br>";

</script>
```